# iOS 9 Realmswift trouble with query

Tags: swift2, ios9, realm

I am trying to get a `Results<News>` of news objects from realm of all objects that have `'mytag'`

The `News` object looks something like

```
dynamic var id = 0
dynamic var title = ""
dynamic var date = NSDate()
dynamic var modified = NSDate()
dynamic var protected = true
dynamic var category : Category?
dynamic var image : Image?
let content = List<Content>()
let tags = List<Tag>()
```

I have a `Results<Tag>` with all my tags. Tag has a boolean `my` to see if it belongs to my tags.

This way I could get personal news.

However, I don't understand how to query this. I have some knowledge of SQL, but i cant seem to figure it out using `contains` or `in`

I tried a workaround but it seems `Results` does not have an `append` function.

Here's my current workaround:

```
func retrieveMyNewsSortedByDate() -> Results<News> {
    let myTags = TagDataService().myTagsList() // retunrs a List<Tag>

    print("My news items");
    let items = database().objects(News).filter("tags IN %@", myTags).sorted("date") // how to query or query with news and tag table
    let myTagItems = List<News>()
    for tag in myTags {
        for news in items{
            for newsTag in news.tags {
                if newsTag == tag {
                    myTagItems.append(news) // Results does not have .append or .addobject
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mytagItems = Results(myTagItems)
    return myTagItems
}
```

However, now I would have a very inefficient way that also outputs list that I can't seem to cast to `Results`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

well, it was quite easy in the end :D

```
 func retrieveMyNewsSortedByDate() -> Results<News> {
    let myTags = TagDataService().myTagsList()

    let items = database().objects(News).filter("ANY tags IN %@", myTags).sorted("date")
    return items
}
```